# How to show only links in nav-bar depending on role with laravel/blade

Tags: php, laravel, navbar, laravel-blade

I've got a navbar and i dont want to show every link it to all users, some links are just for the admin.

in my navbar.blade i got this if statement:

```
@if(Auth::user()->priveleges->admin)
               <li><a href="{{ url('/priveleges/create') }}">Priveleges</a></li>
            @endif
```

privileges is a table relating to my user table and has a row thats admin(boolean)

With that code Im getting a error: Trying to get property of non-object

I also got a function in my user model that i now use for a middleware to check if the user is a admin. This part works though

```
public function isAAdmin()
{
    if(Auth::user()->priveleges){
        if(Auth::user()->priveleges->admin === 1){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I tried to call that function in the navbar aswell but doesnt work.

hope somebody can help

Comment: It's hard to say for sure exactly what the problem is, but I'd look into debugging what `Auth::user()` is actually returning, then `Auth::user()->priviledges` and so on. I would suspect one of the values is not what you're expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would best if you use Laravel Authorization.
For this follow official documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization
or follow this laracast video https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/13

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say but the following error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Usually happens when the returned value is an array but you're not retrieving the data correctly.

If you're still not getting throught this you can still use the `has()`method. Or even better the `whereHas()` method. These methods would probably be helpful in the future as they'll make your life easier when trying to query relations.

[Official doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations)